# How can I get the official Unicode name of a character in Javascript from either its string or numeric value?

Tags: javascript, unicode, character, codepoint

What are my options in JavaScript when I want to find the Unicode name for an arbitrary codepoint?

Maybe there are some modules I can use, web APIs I can call, or people have previously rolled their own way to do this?

It should work with all planes but does not have to handle multi-codepoint strings such as grapheme clusters.

Comment: This looks relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/3799080/2806996

Comment: Dear offtopic closevoter, you may instead wish to put your effort into closing the 2010 version of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798824

Comment: I didn't vote to close as off-topic, but you specifically asked for software libraries or other off-site resources which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on StackOverflow.

Comment: @nwellnhof: No I specifically allowed those as among the possible solutions, as those are typically suggested in SO answers, which are not getting closed. Web APIs and libraries are completely within the topic of computer programming. Perhaps re-inventing wheels is more on-topic somehow? \-:

Comment: As I said, *I* wouldn't have voted to close your question as off-topic. I just wanted to explain why other people might think that it's off-topic.

Comment: @nwellnhof: Thanks. I've seen the same thing on travel.SE where a keyword sets off some trigger happy user who didn't pay much attention to the context.